# Java IO with While and If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, io, while-loop

I want to print contents in two languages both English and Spanish but once i put If statement i am not getting any output though.without  statement i get mixed up out put..please advise me on this regard.Where should i put If statement exactly?

```
Iterator i= selectedDues.iterator();
        pf.write("<div  id=\"div1\">\n");
        System.out.println("D Count :"+ selectedDues.size());
        System.out.println("AppLanguage:" +AppLanguage);

        while (i.hasNext()){

if(AppLanguage.equals("English")) {
            Dues d=(Dues) i.next();
            pf.write("<para>\n");
            pf.write("<p>");
            pf.write("<br/>");
            pf.write("<p>"+ d.getIndustry().getLanguage());
            pf.write("<p>"+d.getIndustry().getApplicantName()+"<br/>");
            pf.write("<p>"+d.getIndustry().getAppAddress()+"<br/>");
            pf.write("<p>"+d.getIndustry().getAppAddLine1()+"<br/>");
            pf.write("<p>"+d.getIndustry().getAppAddLine2()+"<br/>");
            pf.write("<br/>");

                 pf.write("<br/>");
                 pf.write("</p>\n");
                 pf.write("</para>\n");

        }
     }
     else {
               System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
     pf.write("</div>\n");

     pf.write("</body>\n");
     pf.write("</html>\n");
     pf.flush();
     pf.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Step 1: Fix your indentation so everyone else can figure out what your program does.

Comment: @Newbie, You should add more information about `AppLanguage`, `Dues` classes,  `pf`  object and `getIndustry` method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra closing } after your if statement